# Почему возникает ошибка в компоненте React - Too many re-renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function App() {
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    
    const result = notes.map((note, index) => {
        return <p key={index}>{note}</p>;
    });

    const copy = Object.assign([], notes);
    copy.push(6); // так правильно
    setNotes(copy);

    return <div>
        {result}
    </div>;
}
```

Данный код не работает и выдает сообщение об ошибке: **Too many re-renders**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ошибка React: **Too many re-render** говорит о том, что в компоненте образовался бесконечный цикл - рендер -> обновление стейта.

В **функциональных компонентах обновление состояния должно производиться только из функций**, так как сам компонент может многократно вызываться, а работает компонент как обычная функция, т.е. выполняется весь код в функции.

В вашем примере вы вызывали `setNotes()` в теле компонента, который срабатывал каждый раз при обновлении сосотояния и установке/изменении компонента в DOM. 
Для исправления данной ошибки, необходимо перенести изменение состояния компонента в функцию:

```
function App() {
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    const [result, setResult] = useState(null);
    // Функция, которая меняет состояние компонента
    const addNote = (item) => {
        const copy = Object.assign([], notes);
        copy.push(item); // так правильно
        setNotes(copy);
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setResult(notes.map((note, index) => {
            return <p key={index}>{note}</p>;
        }));
    }, [notes, notes.length])

    return <div>
        {result}
        <button onClick={() => addNote(notes.length + 1)}>add</button>
    </div>;
}
```

Хотя я бы рекомендовал рендерить массив в методе render(В функциональном компоненте это return)

```
function App() {
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    
    const addNote = (item) => {
        const copy = Object.assign([], notes);
        copy.push(item); // так правильно
        setNotes(copy);
    }

    return <div>
        {notes.map((note, index) => {
            return <p key={index}>{note}</p>;
        })}
        <button onClick={() => addNote(notes.length + 1)}>add</button>
    </div>;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю! А как можно модифицировать код для удаления или сортировки?

Comment: Если принимаешь ответ, нажми на галочку слева от ответа(принять ответ). По поводу вопроса - как изменить: любым удобным способом при [работе с массивами](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods). Как только массив будет изменен и записан в стейт, автоматом вызовется рендер

Comment: А так, попробуйте самостоятельно реализовать методы добавления, удаления, модификации массива, сортировки. Не получится, приходите с вашим кодом, показывайте, подскажут. Соблюдайте правила в виде 1 пост, 1 вопрос )

Comment: Ваш код отлично работает и с другими методами, правда, не пойму, почему там useFetch или почему map работает  внутри return, а если написать снаружи, выдает ошибку

Comment: @ЕвгенийЧерник Добавил новый ответ с описанием, что происходит внутри функционального компонента.

Answer (score 1):

## React.JS: Too many re-renders

### Причины возникновения и способы устранения

> **Функциональные компоненты React(Function component)** работают в React так же, как функции в обычном javaScript. Т.е. что бы отрисовать компонент, код компонента(функции) читается и выполняется с начала({) и до конца(}) как обычная функция javaScript.

#### Обновление состояния компонента вне функции данного компонента

Для примера, давайте посмотрим на этот функциональный компонент:

```
let i = 0; // Объявлена за пределами функции
export default function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
  
  const addNote = (item) => {
      const copy = Object.assign([], notes);
      copy.push(item); // так правильно
      setNotes(copy);
  }
  console.log(++i)

  return <div>
      {notes.map((note, index) => {
          return <p key={index}>{note}</p>;
      })}
      <button onClick={() => addNote(notes.length + 1)}>add</button>
  </div>;
}
```

Как мы видим в консоли разработчика, что каждое действие(установка компонентов в DOM и нажатие на кнопку) сопровождается вызовом функции и выводом в консоль. 
Это означает, что все что описано вне функций, внутри функционального компонента, вызывается при событии обновления состояния компонента.

---

Теперь возьмем ваш код и подумаем, что же будет происходить, *если вызывать изменение состояния компонента вне функции*.

Вот ваш пример, который выдает ошибку **too many re-renders**:

```
let i = 0;
export default function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
  
  const addNote = (item) => {
      const copy = Object.assign([], notes);
      copy.push(item); // так правильно
      setNotes(copy);
  }
  // Изменяем состояние компонента.
  setNotes(() => {
    const c = notes;
    c.push(++i);
    return c;
  });

  console.log(i, notes);

  return <div>
      {notes.map((note, index) => {
          return <p key={index}>{note}</p>;
      })}
      <button onClick={() => addNote(notes.length + 1)}>add</button>
  </div>;
}
```

Давайте разберем, что происходит в этой функции! Идем по порядку, читаем функцию и выполняем...
Создается хранилище, создается функция `addNote`. Вызывается `setNotes`(асинхронная функция). Далее вывод в консоль и рендер.

Срабатывает `setNotes` вызванный ранее и меняет состояние. Запускается рендер, бежим по коду компонента -> хранилище есть -> функция есть -> вызываем `setNotes` -> вывод в консоль и рендер.
Срабатывает `setNotes` вызванный ранее и меняет состояние. Запускается рендер, бежим по коду компонента -> хранилище есть -> функция есть -> вызываем `setNotes` -> вывод в консоль и рендер.
Срабатывает `setNotes` вызванный ранее и меняет состояние. Запускается рендер, бежим по коду компонента -> хранилище есть -> функция есть -> вызываем `setNotes` -> вывод в консоль и рендер.
Срабатывает `setNotes` вызванный ранее и меняет состояние. Запускается рендер, бежим по коду компонента -> хранилище есть -> функция есть -> вызываем `setNotes` -> вывод в консоль и рендер.

---

Т.к. это не прекратится никогда, вы получаете логичную ошибку **React: Too many re-renders**.

#### Неявный вызов обновления состояния компонента из события элемента

Давайте изменим наш код. С виду кажется, что очень даже работоспособный код, однако он тоже приведет к ошибке **React: Too many re-renders**.

```
let i = 0;
export default function App() {
  const [numClick, setNumClick] = useState(0);
  
  console.log(i);

  return <div>
      {numClick}
      <button onClick={setNotes(c => c++)}>Add click</button>
  </div>;
}
```

> Выполнение обновления состояния компонента в событиях элемента должно быть обёрнуто в функцию, иначе javaScript воспринимает `setNotes(c => c++)` как вызов обычной функции javaScript `func()`.
> Так как setNotes действительно является функцией, то происходит ее вызов в момент рендера компонента. А далее по кругу.

#### useEffect без массива зависимостей

```
useEffect(() => {
    setNotes(n => ++n);
});
```

Такое может быть расценено браузером как вызов фукнции -> `someFunctin()` что приведент к зацикливанию и ошибке.

#### Циклическая зависимость через useEffect

В большом количестве кода, с большим количеством переменных состояния компонента можно допустить ошибку, когда через хук useEffect состояние компонента будет бесконечно и бесконтрольно обновляться.
В функциональных компонентах, **каждое** изменение состояния происходит последовательно, друг за другом, по мере вызова обновления, хотя и асинхронно, т.е. порядок не гарантирован.

Рассмотрим данный код, как пример, в котором как раз реализована циклическая зависимость одной переменной состояния от другой.

```
let i = 0;
export default function App() {
  const [numClick, setNumClick] = useState(2);
  const [res, setRes] = useState(4)
  
  console.log(i);
  
  useEffect(() => {
      setRes(numClick ** 2);
  }, [numClick]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
      setNumClick(e => ++e);
  }, [res]);

  return <div>
      {numClick}
      <button onClick={() => setNumClick(e => ++e)}>Возвести в квадрат</button>
  </div>;
}
```

Как видно из примера, при нажатии на кнопку, вызывается обновление состояния переменной numClick. 
Когда состояние изменится, запустится хук `useEffect()` с зависимостью numClick.
Когда обновится состояние res, запустится хук `useEffect()` с зависимостью res, который обновит состояние переменной numClick.
Когда состояние изменится, запустится хук `useEffect()` с зависимостью numClick.
Когда обновится состояние res, запустится хук `useEffect()` с зависимостью res, который обновит состояние переменной numClick.

И так далее до получения ошибки **React: Too many re-renders**.

Я надеюсь, с этим примером вам станет более понятно, как работают **функциональные компоненты React** и каких действий с обновление состояния компонента следует избегать для предотвращения появления ошибки *React: Too many re-renders*.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function App() {const [notes, setNotes] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

const result = notes.map((note, index) => {
    return <p key={index}>{note}</p>;
});

setNotes([...notes, 6]);

return <div>
    {result}
</div>;
}
```

Comment: Все равно выдает Too many re-renders