# Не подтягивается переменная с повторного fetch. Запутался в коде. React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Беру из API курс валют за 30 дней. Сделал вьібор валют селекторами, куда подтянул данньіе из json, сделал два поля в которьіх подсчитьівается курс одной валютьі относительно другой. Если менять вьіходную валюту, то подтягивается новое отношение из єтого же файла json. Если менять входную, то делается новьій запрос, в котором будут новьіе отношения между валютами. У меня запрос делается, а отношения валют не стают новьіми при смене верхней валютьі.
Вот код App.js. Второй запрос делается на 60 строке, в нем и проблема:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import CurrencyRow from './CurrencyRow'

var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("apikey", "seNJp91EYSFBx6e6XV00radMdjKULvrl")

var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    redirect: 'follow',
    headers: myHeaders
};

const BASE_URL = 'https://api.apilayer.com/exchangerates_data/timeseries?start_date=2022-09-01&end_date=2022-10-01' //& base=UAH

function App() {
    const [currencyOptions, setCurrencyOptions] = useState([])
    const [fromCurrency, setFromCurrency] = useState()
    const [toCurrency, setToCurrency] = useState()
    const [exchangeRate, setExchangeRate] = useState()
    const [amount, setAmount] = useState(1)
    const [amountInFromCurrency, setAmountInFromCurrency] = useState(true)

    const [rates, setRates] = useState({})
    const [dates, setDates] = useState([])
    const [rateRender, setRateRender] = useState([])

    let toAmount, fromAmount
    if (amountInFromCurrency) {
        fromAmount = amount
        toAmount = amount * exchangeRate
    } else {
        toAmount = amount
        fromAmount = amount / exchangeRate
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(BASE_URL, requestOptions)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                const keys = Object.keys(data.rates)
                setDates([...keys])
                setRates(data.rates)
                let names = []
                let values = []
                rateRender.map(item => {
                    names.push(item.name)
                    values.push(item.value)
                })
                setCurrencyOptions([...Object(names)])
                setFromCurrency(data.base)
                setToCurrency(names[0])
                let n = names.indexOf(toCurrency)
                setExchangeRate(values[n])
                console.log(data)
            })
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        //if (fromCurrency != null && toCurrency != null) {
            fetch(`${BASE_URL}&base=${fromCurrency}&sybmols=${toCurrency}`, requestOptions)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    const keys = Object.keys(data.rates)
                    setDates([...keys])
                    setRates(data.rates)

                    let names = []
                    let values = []
                    rateRender.map(item => {
                        names.push(item.name)
                        values.push(item.value)
                    })
                    let n = names.indexOf(toCurrency)
                    setExchangeRate(values[n])
                    console.log(data)
                    console.log(fromCurrency, " ", toCurrency, " ", exchangeRate)
                })
        //}
    }, [fromCurrency, toCurrency])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (dates.length && !rateRender.length) {
            getRates(dates[0])
        }
    }, [dates])

    const getRates = (date) => {
        const rateSelect = rates[date];
        const rate = [];
        for (let x in rateSelect) {
            rate.push({
                name: x,
                value: rateSelect[x]
            })
        }
        setRateRender(rate)
    }

    function handleFromAmountChange(e) {
        setAmount(e.target.value)
        setAmountInFromCurrency(true)
    }

    function handleToAmountChange(e) {
        setAmount(e.target.value)
        setAmountInFromCurrency(false)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Currency</h1>
            <CurrencyRow
                currencyOptions={currencyOptions}
                selectedCurrency={fromCurrency}
                onChangeCurrency={e => setFromCurrency(e.target.value)}
                onChangeAmount={e => handleFromAmountChange(e)}
                amount={fromAmount}
            />
            <div id="equal">=</div>
            <CurrencyRow
                currencyOptions={currencyOptions}
                selectedCurrency={toCurrency}
                onChangeCurrency={e => setToCurrency(e.target.value)}
                onChangeAmount={e => handleToAmountChange(e)}
                amount={toAmount}
            />
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Для понятливости вот еще js в котором поля ввода и селекторьі:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function CurrencyRow(props) {
    const {
        currencyOptions,
        selectedCurrency,
        onChangeCurrency,
        onChangeAmount,
        amount
    } = props
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="number" value={amount} onChange={onChangeAmount} />
            <select value={selectedCurrency} onChange={onChangeCurrency} >
                {currencyOptions.map(option => (
                    <option key={option} value={option}>{option}</option>
                ))}
            </select>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Далее наглядньіе скриншотьі уже на сайте:

Евро к первой валюте из списка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Евро к любой другой просто для примера работоспособности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Доллар к первой валюте. Значение как и у евро:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот для проверки вьівел в консоль то, что отношение валют вообще не меняется, при том что поступает новьій запрос с другим base.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как вьіглядит наполнение json из API:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь хоть что-то понятно расписал. Я в реакте только осваиваюсь и, можно сказать, учился пока писал. Опьіт есть в других язьіках. Не могу просто понять в какой момент в коде и что я должен переприсвоить, чтобьі отношения валют после второго fetch`а стали новьіми.

Comment: let toAmount, fromAmount - Это что такое? Вынесите их в стейт и они у вас должны обновляться при изменении. Сейчас это если и происходит, то это побочный эффект раз [рассказывал тут, почитайте, полезно будет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457575/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-react/1457948#1457948), два - это не состояние и реакт повторно это рендерить не будет.

Comment: Сделал как вьі порекомендовали, вьінес єти переменньіе в стейт, появилась ошибка такая, как и в вопросе, на которьій вьі сослались. Изменил условие вьізова на функцию, которая вьізьівается при вьізове handleFrom(To)AmountChange (в исходном коде єтот кусок бьіл просто if). Счетчик стал чуть странно работать, но проблема у меня все равно бьіла не в єтом, єто все работало. У меня не подтягивает новьіе данньіе второй селектор.

Comment: function settingAmount() {
        //let toAmount, fromAmount
        if (amountInFromCurrency) {
            //fromAmount = amount
            //toAmount = amount * exchangeRate
            setFromAmount(amount)
            setToAmount(amount * exchangeRate)
        } else {
            //toAmount = amount
            //fromAmount = amount / exchangeRate
            setToAmount(amount)
            setFromAmount(amount / exchangeRate)
        }
    }

Comment: Обновите ваш код и добавьте внесенные изменения. Изменить вопрос можно, нажав "кнопку" править внизу вопроса, так очень сложно понять, как теперь выглядит ваш код