# React проблема бесконечного ререндеринга

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hook, create-react-app, useeffect

Написал свой кастомный хук для отправления запросов, и иногра нужно вручную повторить запрос в компоненте. Но происходит бесконечное зацикливание. С работой хука ознакомился, но не пойму почему возникает эта ошибка в моей ситуации. Буду рад объяснению

Есть кастомный хук, которвм я пользуюсь в компонентах

```
const useRequest = (url: string, method: Method, config: IRequestConfig = {}) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<any | null>(null)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null)
  const [again, setAgain] = useState<boolean>(true)

  if (config.baseUrl) {
    url = config.baseUrl + url
  }

  const refresh = () => setAgain(!again)

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    axios[method](url, config)
        .then(response => {
          setData(response.data)
        })
        .catch((error: AxiosError) => {
          setError(error.message)
        })
        .finally(() => setLoading(false))
  }, [again])

  return {data, loading, error, refresh}
}
```

При вызове хука все работает нормально, но при повторном использовании запроса происходит бесконечный цикл

```
  const {data, refresh} = useRequest(url, method, {baseUrl: BASE_API_URL})
  refresh()
```

Comment: Только что пришло понимание возникающей проблемы кажется. У меня идет высов refresh, он приводик с смене значения data, и это приводит к перерендыванию и повторному вызову refresh. Возможно проблемы не будет если я refresh буду вешать на кнопки. Но могу ошибаться

Comment: Возможно это ответ на ваш вопрос [react roo many rerenders](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457575/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5-react-too-many-re-renders/1457588#1457588)