# React setComponent

Tags: reactjs

Помогите,как сделать мне нужно если чекбокс равен тру то выполняется условия которое записывает данные в const, но оно не хочет работать

```
    function Sz() {
    const[test, setTest] = useState("true");
    const[test2, setTest2] = useState("true");
    const ww = test;
    const year = ww;
    if (year  == true ) {
        setTest2{"block"};
        console.log("тру")
        } 
        else {
            setTest2{"none"};
            console.log("фальш")
            } 
    console.log(test, test2, year)
    return (
        <>
    <Checkbox onChange={(e) => setTest2(e.target.checked)}>
    Под 0% 
  </Checkbox>
```

Comment: Возможно это решение вашей проблемы. Не обновляйте состояние вне функций, это приводит к [ошибке too many re renders](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457575/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5-react-too-many-re-renders/1457948#1457948). Так же у вас ошибка в условии. Состояние вы устанавливаете строку, а сравнивете с булиновым значением

Comment: Сделал так
if (year  == true ) {
        setTest2{"block"};
        console.log("тру")
        } 
        if (year  == false ) {
        setTest2{"block"};
        console.log("фалсе")
        } 
    console.log(test, test2, year)
    return (
        <>
    <Checkbox onChange={(e) => setTest2(e.target.checked)}>
    Под 0% 
  </Checkbox>

Comment: После этого заработало?

Comment: Да)) теперь у меня другая проблема, как можно по одному onchange записать данные в 2 переменные?))

Comment: Берете и вызываете **set[Value]** нужных переменных