# Error: Minified React error #310

Tags: reactjs

Возникает ошибка после того как приходят данные с API в мое приложения. Как мне понять где возникает ошибка. Хочу сразу сказать, что я изучил данную тему и проверил, что хуки не вызываются в условии. Так же я проверил все компоненты на правильность переданных пропсов в дочерний компонент. В чем еще может быть проблема, или где она может быть?
Вот данная ошибка:

```
Error: Minified React error #310; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=310 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изучил данную статью: [тык](https://medium.com/@jonchurch/how-to-fix-react-error-rendered-fewer-hooks-than-expected-e6a378985d3c)

в этих хуках данные (adDepth и offer) прилетает по сокетам в компонент. Может из за этого быть ошибка?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    prepareData();

    if (forScreen) {
      return;
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getStaticDepth();

    if (!blockAnim) {
      setIsShow(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setIsShow(false);
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (adDepth?.depth) {
      makeDepthData(adDepth?.depth);
    }
  }, [
    adDepth?.depth,
    offer.price,
    offer.minAmount,
    offer.maxAmount,
    offer.config,
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    prepareSettlementRate();
  }, [userData?.targetPrices]);
```

Вот где проблема:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(pageIndex, pageSize);
  }, [fetchData, pageIndex, pageSize]);
```

Сама функция fetchData

```
  const fetchData = useCallback(async (pageNumber?: number, pageSize: number = 10, params?: FilterParams) => {
    const skip = pageNumber && pageSize ? pageNumber * pageSize : 0;
    setIsLoading(true);
    const {dealList, count} = await fetchTradeHistory(skip, pageSize, params);
    setPageCount(Math.ceil(count / pageSize));
    setTradeHistoryItems(dealList);
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Проверьте, что в хуках зависимости не цикличны`useEffect(() => setC()}, [a, b, c])`. Или нет 2-х хуков, которые циклично дергают друг-друга по очереди `useEffect(() => setA()}, [b]); useEffect(() => setB()}, [a])`

Comment: Я дополню вопрос useEffect которые у меня отрабатывают при сценарии ошибки. Может быть дело в том, что у меня по сокетам приходят данные adDepth и offer и из за этого у меня useEffect вызывается меньше раз чем должен или примерно в таком духе, пока не очень улавливаю логику, но мне кажется, что в этом может быть дело.

Comment: `makeDepthData` и `prepareSettlementRate` выполняют изменение состояния компонента? +объедините 2 эффект с зависимостью [] в один

Comment: Я нашел в чем дело! Как вы и говорили, есть хук в котором работает рекурсия, но дело в том, что  функция fetchData приходит из родителя, которая обернута в useCallback - она должна нормально работать, но не работает. Как только я закоментировал useEffect вместе с функцией fetchData - все стало нормально - осталось понять как исправить этот момент, ведь мне нужна эта логика в useEffect.

Comment: Обернув компонент в React.memo() я решил данную проблему! Спасибо большое за помощь и правильное направление мысли!

Comment: Можете еще почитать [про хуки и ошибки с useEffect](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457575/1457948#1457948). Возможно тоже наведет на мысли, где что исправить и каких действий стоит избегать.