# В консоле вместо одного запроса выдает 6

Tags: javascript, next.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styles  from '../Card/Card.module.css'
import Link from 'next/link';



function Card() {
    const {query} = useRouter()
    const [data, setData] - useState([])
    console.log(query)

    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    
     
    useEffect(()=>{
      fetch(``)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => setData(result))
      },[])
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так выходит у меня информация в консоле
Что могу сделать ?
Пишу в Next.js

Comment: Почему так не должно быть? Ну 6 выводов, что с того? Значит 6 раз компонент обновлял сотояние

Comment: [Как работают функциональные компоненты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457575/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5-react-too-many-re-renders/1457948?r=Saves_UserSavesList#1457948) - давал ссылку вчера. Ознакомились? Если вставите `console.log()` в `useEffect()`, то сообщение появится 1 раз, в момент установки компонента в **DOM**

Comment: @SwaD значит это можно также применить к Next.js?

Comment: А почему бы нет?