# use effect сам повторяется

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hook

После запуска код начинает сам повторяться (делается бесконечный цикл) и крашится

`

```
const [track_data, set_track_data] = React.useState({})

React.useEffect(()=>{

    var datas = {

    "name":"test"

    }


    set_track_data({datas})

    };

})
```

`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает ошибка в компоненте React - Too many re-renders?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457575/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5-react-too-many-re-renders)

Comment: @SwaD Причины разные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам определённо надо почитать как работает [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Если вкратце, то `useEffect` вызывается самый первый раз при инициализации компоненты и в каждый следующий раз, когда обновляется состояние компоненты

Вот и у вас при инициализации вызывается `useEffect`, который внутри себя запускает обновление состояния (`set_track_data`). После обновления состояния опять вызывается `useEffect`, который опять запускает обновление состояния и т.о. это продолжается бесконечно:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;


const App = () => {
  const [track_data, set_track_data] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
      var datas = {
        "name":"test"
      }
      
      console.log("I'm updated");

      set_track_data(datas);
  });
  
  return (
    <div>{track_data.name}</div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Судя по коду, который вы опубликовали, вам надо просто при инициализации компоненты, записать значение в `track_data`. Для этого `useEffect` вообще можно не использовать, а просто поставить это значение как начальное значение:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  var datas = {
    "name":"test"
  }
  
  const [track_data, set_track_data] = useState(datas);
  
  console.log('Updated');
  
  return (
    <div>{track_data.name}</div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Если же это просто вырезанный кусок кода, где вам надо вызвать `useEffect` всего один раз, то вам надо просто передать пустой [массив зависимостей](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects), тогда `useEffect` сработает всего 1 раз при инициализации:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;


const App = () => {
  const [track_data, set_track_data] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
      var datas = {
        "name":"test"
      }
      
      console.log("I'm updated");

      set_track_data(datas);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>{track_data.name}</div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Если не использовать useEffect всё ровно та же проблема. Передача пустого массива зависимостей сработало

Comment: @АртёмВаганов Вы что-то не то делаете значит, я добавил `console.log('Updated')` к варианту без `useEffect` и он срабатвает единожды. Тем не менее рад что смог помочь