# Почему useEffect не показывает элементы из массива?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть массив данных. Каждому повесил `ref`, чтобы потом перебрать все элементы. Но в `useEffect` ничего не консолится. Элементы я получаю только когда страница будет готова и я сделаю какое нибудь изменение на странице, тогда консолится.`StrictMode` убран. Почему так и как фиксить?

[Рабочий пример, с таким же подходом](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Ihatetomatoes/gsap-scrolltrigger-react-tutorial/?file=/src/App.js:1141-1652)

[image]

```
const array = [
  {
    title: "Ref Element 1"
  },
  {
    title: "Ref Element 2"
  },
  {
    title: "Ref Element 3"
  }
];

const revealRefs = useRef([]);
revealRefs.current = [];

useEffect(() => {
  revealRefs.current.forEach((element) => {
    console.log(element);
  })
}, []);

const addToRefs = (element) => {
  if (element && !revealRefs.current.includes(element)) {
    revealRefs.current.push(element);
  }
}

<section className="container">
   {array.map((element) => (
     <div className="element" ref={addToRefs}>{element.title}</div>    
    ))}  
</section>
```

Comment: А в `deps` `useEffect`'а, пытались добавить `revealRefs.current`?

Comment: Что вы вообще хотите сделать? Зачем для простого отображения вы ипользуете `useRef`? В доках кстати сказано, что изменение `.current` не вызывает ререндер ([почитайте последний абзац](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1482394/use-effect-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f/1482430#1482430))

Comment: @EzioMercer Да у меня салйдер, где 17 изображений, текст и тд. Поэтому такие манипуляции делаю

Comment: Вы читали мой ответ? Если да, то внесите пожалуйста соответствующие правки в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Я кстати запустил ваш код и в консоли всё печатается и на странице всё отображается сразу без всяких манипуляций. Если я что-то не так понял, то скопируйте мой код нажав на "Править" и вставьте себе в вопрос и измените его как вам нужно и убедитесь что всё происходит точно так как вы ожидаете

```js
const {useRef, useEffect} = React;

const App = () => {
  const array = [{
      title: "Ref Element 1"
    },
    {
      title: "Ref Element 2"
    },
    {
      title: "Ref Element 3"
    }
  ];

  const revealRefs = useRef([]);
  revealRefs.current = [];

  useEffect(() => {
    revealRefs.current.forEach((element) => {
      console.log(element);
    })
  }, []);

  const addToRefs = (element) => {
    if (element && !revealRefs.current.includes(element)) {
      revealRefs.current.push(element);
    }
  }

  return (
    <section className="container">
       {array.map((element) => (
         <div className="element" ref={addToRefs}>{element.title}</div>    
        ))}  
    </section>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App /> , document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```