# Постоянная перезагрузка с использованием тернарного оператора (React)

Tags: reactjs, axios, useeffect

Есть код в App.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';    
import PostService from './API/PostService';    
  
const [isPostsLoading, setIsPostsLoading] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts()
  }, [filter, posts, modal])

  async function fetchPosts() {
    setIsPostsLoading(true);
    const posts = await PostService.getAll();
    setPosts(posts);
    setIsPostsLoading(false);
  }

  {isPostsLoading
    ? <h1>Идёт загрузка...</h1>
    : <PostList remove={removePost} posts={sortedAndSearchedPosts} title="Посты про Web" />
  }
```

Код в PostService.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default class PostService {
    static async getAll () {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
            return response.data
        } catch {
            console.log('error')
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что у меня постоянная перезагрузка страницы идёт с этим кодом. Сначала пишет `<h1>Идёт загрузка...</h1>`, а потом `<PostList remove={removePost} posts={sortedAndSearchedPosts} title="Посты про Web" />`, а потом снова через полсекунды пишет, что идёт загрузка, потом снова про посты про Web... И это всё продолжается бесконечность. Такое ощущение, что мой код автоматически перезагружает страницу...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает ошибка в компоненте React - Too many re-renders?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457575/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5-react-too-many-re-renders)

Comment: У меня даже ошибка не выскакивает

Comment: Но суть остается, скорее всего той же. Вы запускаете `useEffect` по зависимостям `[filter, posts, modal]` который дергает функцию `fetchPosts` которая в свою очередь через n времени обновляет `posts` и `isPostsLoading`, что запускает `useEffect` и вызов функции `fetchPosts` которая в свою очередь через n времени обновляет `posts`. Можно продолжать так бесконечно. А ошибки нет, потому что между рендерами проходит достаточно времени. В ссылке выше, во втором ответе эта ситуация указана, но на примере 2х useEffect

Comment: Убрал posts - помогло. Спасибо!