# Компонент реакт не появляется на странице

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Ребят, помогите пожалуйста!

Я вставляла секцию на сайт (React/TypeScript) и в какой-то момент она исчезла -не могу вернуть ее(( Хотя код не меняла (только картинки).

Я совсем новичок в реакте и тем более в ТС (не судите строго, пожалуйста) подскажите, что нужно исправить?

Выбрала участки кода, относящиеся к вопросу

```js
import React from "react";
import cx from "classnames";
import styles from "./Advantages.module.scss";


export interface AdvantagesProps {

}

export function Advantages({ }: AdvantagesProps) {   
  return (
   <section className={styles.container}>
      <ul className={styles.list}>
        <li className={styles['list-item']}>
          <div className={styles['list-item-header']}>
            <span className={cx(styles['list-item-header-icon'], styles.icon1)} />
            <h3 className={styles['list-item-header-title']}>
           заголовок/>
            </h3>
          </div>
          <p className={styles['list-item-description']}>
         здесь текст параграфа
          </p>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
      );
};
```

```html
import {
  Advantages,
} from "../../features";


export default function Home({ eraTemplate }: any) {

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
      getCountriesProcessing();
    }
  });

  return (
    <InsuranceTemplate>
      <Advantages />
    </InsuranceTemplate>
  )
}
```

Comment: У вас `useEffect` без зависимостей, это может приводить к ошибкам [too many re-renders](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457575/1457948/1457948) - Посмотрите в консоли, нет ли там этой ошибки.

Comment: @SwaD нет, такой ошибки не вижу(( особо ничего не меняла (вот useEffect точне не трогала, но оно все равно пропало) :(

Comment: Может другие ошибки есть? Видимых причин, почему не отображается компонент я не вижу. Может в стилях скрыт, а может вообще не рендерится впринципе. Попробуйте `console.log()` разных понавставлять в эти компоненты и посмотрите, что происходит и происходит ли вообще

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, что я нахожусь на другой странице. Она выглядит так же, как и та, на которой находятся новые компоненты.

Comment: Т.е. мы пытались искать черного кота в темной комнате, в которой этого кота нет...

Comment: ахаха ну простите, пожалуйста((
я, как освоюсь, тоже буду новичкам помогать :DD

Comment: Все в порядке )

Comment: Кстати, хотите что бы человек, к которому вы обращаетесь получил уведомление, ставьте @ и его ник. Владелец вопроса\ответом получает все уведомления

Comment: @SwaD , окей, спасибо! :D