# Как вызвать const из const с актуальным useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Когда мы вызывает одну функцию из другой. То значения получаем изначальное. Возможно ли актуальное?

```
   const [text, setText] = useState('привет');
    
    useEffect(() => {
      add();
    });
    
    const add = () => {
      setText('пока');
      get();
    }
    
    const get = () => {
      console.log(text); //вернет привет
    }
```

Comment: Ваш код скорее всего выдаст ошибку [too many re-renders](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457575/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5-react-too-many-re-renders/1457948#1457948). Изменение состояния - асинхронная операция. Если измененные данные хотите передавать по функциям, то передавайте как параметр

Comment: Можно делать функцию `get `, используя хук `useCallback`. В зависимостях нужно будет указать переменную `text`. https://webtricks-master.ru/react-hooks/uchim-usecallback-na-primerah-react-hooks/