# Бесконечный вызов функции

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, xmlhttprequest

Есть функция которая отправляет запрос на сервер и присваивает ответ в переменную внутри стора.

```
const temperature = async() => {
   let data = await fetchWeather(35) //функция что отправляет запрос 
   console.log(data)
   temp1.setData(data[0].temp2) //temp1 - название хранилища, temp2 - ключ объекта 
} 
temperature()
```

все работает как и должно, но если вместо data[0]
.temp попытаться присвоить data или data[0], то есть присвоить весь массив а не только значение ключа temp2, в логах начинается бесконечный поток данных

функция что передает данные:

```
export const fetchWeather = async(id) => {
  const {data} = await $host.get(`api/weather/${id}`)
  return data
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему возникает ошибка в компоненте React - Too many re-renders?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457575/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5-react-too-many-re-renders)

Comment: Надо смотреть, какие там у вас зависимости выставлены. + я надеюсь, `temperature()` не в теле функции, а обернуто во что то? Иначе оно будет вызываться каждый раз при перерисовке компонента. И так же, если temp2 у вас не меняется, то, возможно, и перерисовки нет, а когда вы добавляете весь объект, то реакт поимает, что данные изменились

Comment: увы, но нет, у меня состояние в стейт менеджере, обновляется оно в функции(что и было решением проблемы в предложенном вами вопросе) к тому же она вызывается до компонента, и ошибки все таки у меня нет, просто вызывается функция почему-то без конца

Comment: temperature() объявлена и вызывается до объявление компонента, визуально ничего не меняется, только в логах один и тот же ответ выводится бесконечное количество раз, при присваивании data[0].temp один раз выводится лог с data, при обновлении страницы аналогично, один раз, нет никаких лишних перерисовок, но стоит удалить .temp из присваивания, ничего больше не изменяя, начинается 100+ выводов в консоли за секунду

Comment: @qwothex полный и максимально минимальный код скинь, что бы можно было понять. По идее  тебя там ошибка и data[0] .temp просто нечего не обновляет.

Comment: Значит что то все таки вызывает эту функцию. Добавьте в вопрос больше данных по вашему компоненту.