# ошибка при добавлении значения в массив state в react

Tags: reactjs

Я хочу условно добавить значение в массив. Это `state` и функция добавления:

```
const [Selectors, setSelectors] = useState([]);
const SelectorAdd = (newValue) => {
   setSelectors((array) => [...array, newValue]);
}
```

И я просто хочу добавить любое текстовое значение в массив `Selectors` внутри этого условия:

```
{Yes ?
   <>
      <AnyComponent />
      {SelectorAdd('text value')} <=== ТУТ
   </>
: null}
```

И получаю эту ошибку:

```
Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка? Спасибо!

Comment: [react - too many re-renders](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457575/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5-react-too-many-re-renders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SelectorAdd() => setSelectors() => перересовка => заного по кругу бесконечно

```
const A = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  const [yes, setYes] = useState(true)

  // //не правилный способ
  // if (yes) {
  //   //запускает перересовку бесконечно
  //   setState((prev) => ++prev);
  // }

  //правильный
  useEffect(() => {
    if (yes) {
      setState((prev) => ++prev);
    }
  }, [yes]);

  //не имеет смысла внутри юзать setState
  return yes && <div>что то</div>;
};
```

Comment: Ошибку исправил другим путем! Спасибо!

Comment: @rabbit надеюсь исправил правильно, учти каждый раз когда вызываеш setState все внутри компоненты запускается заного. В дочерних тоже если React.memo не юзается. Ну кроме хуков остальных.

Comment: @rabbit Покажите, как вы исправили ошибку, возможно будет полезно другим пользователям

Comment: @SwaD, Мне нужно было заносить селекторы в массив, используя два плагина совместно moveable и selecto. Проблему решил совершенно другим путем, используя конкретный класс, не используя массив вообще. Поэтому, я не думаю, что это будет кому-то полезно.